# Why can't run program from CodePen using ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I found a React project on CodePen, it's an [ios like caculator](http://codepen.io/mjijackson/pen/xOzyGX).Some syntax errors occurs like this:

```
ERROR in ./app/index.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (45:19)

  43 | class CalculatorDisplay extends React.Component {
  44 |   render() {
> 45 |     const { value, ...props } = this.props
```

and this:

```
ERROR in ./app/index.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:8)

  2 |
  3 | class AutoScalingText extends React.Component {
> 4 |   state = {
    |         ^
  5 |     scale: 1
  6 |   };
```

Loader configs in my `webpack.config.js` is:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=8192"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I know there is some syntax used not supported in ES2015,but how does it run in CodePen,is there any newer ES edition supports these syntax?

Comment: Click on settings icon next to JS pane, select `Babel`. There is also [ES6fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/)

Comment: CodePen is oksy,i mean i can't run it in my own project using webpack.@Tushar

Comment: You need to configure Babel to use the plugins for the features you are using. *"how does it run in CodePen"* Maybe they enable all experimental features by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using babel make sure that you have the following packages in the node_module. If not you can install them like

```
npm i babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react -S
```

Your webpack loaders seems to be properly configured. you must specify the initial state inside a constructor like

```
class AutoScalingText extends React.Component {
constructor(){
     this.state = {  
           scale: 1
      };
}
```

If your use the npm package babel-preset-state-0 then the syntax that you use is valid. You need to install it like

```
npm install -S babel-preset-stage-0
```

and in your webpack use it like

```
 {
    test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
    }
  }
```

Comment: But why can't declare class properties in class level other than in constructor like the code in CodePen.I know it's illegal in ECMA2015,but which version support these syntax?

Comment: Edited teh answer for that

Comment: I tried to install `class-properties` and `object-rest-spread`, then it worked.But your solution is universally useful.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you accept this answer, does it work for you, if you try this rather than what you commented